# RecyclerView make endless scrolling with JSON

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make my Android App (I'm only experienced in iOS).

I created a RecyclerView that gets the data from a web. I tried everything to implement endless scrolling to load more items, but when I call the function to get the items, the entire RecyclerView loads again and no attach the new results on the bottom.

This is my code:

**ConversationUser.kt**

```
 data class ConversationUser(
     val message_nickname: String, 
     val message_image_thumb: String, 
     val message_large_thumb: String, 
     val message_modified: String, 
     val message_status: String, 
     val message_unread: Int, 
     val conv_id: String, 
     val message_dest: String) {
 }
```

**ConversacionesActivity.kt**

```
class ConversacionesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

// MARK: Variables

var user_token = ""
var user_id = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    // User Defaults

    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    user_token = sharedPreferences.getString("user_token", "")!!
    user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", "")!!

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversaciones)

    recyclerConv.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))

    getConversationsData()

    recyclerConv.setLoadingListener(object : LoadingListener {
        override fun onRefresh() {
            //refresh data here
            
        }

        override fun onLoadMore() {
            // load more data here
            getConversationsData()

        }
    })
}

fun getConversationsData() {

    val httpAsync = "https://mywebsite.com/conversations/${user_token}"
        .httpPost()
        .responseString { request, response, result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    val ex = result.getException()
                    println(ex)
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val data = result.get()
                    runOnUiThread {
                        val conversaciones = processJson(data)
                        show(conversaciones)

                        return@runOnUiThread
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    httpAsync.join()

}

fun processJson(json: String): List<ConversationUser> {
    val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val conversaciones: List<ConversationUser> = gson.fromJson(
        json,
        Array<ConversationUser>::class.java
    ).toList()

    return conversaciones
}

fun show(conversaciones: List<ConversationUser>) {
    recyclerConv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerConv.adapter = AdaptadorConv(conversaciones, this, user_token, user_id)

}
```

**AdaptadorConv.kt**

```
class AdaptadorConv(
val conversaciones: List<ConversationUser> = ArrayList(),
val context: Context,
val user_token: String,
val user_id: String) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorConv.ConvViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ConvViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.convName.text = conversaciones[position].message_nickname
    
    holder.convTime.text = conversaciones[position].message_modified
    
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return conversaciones.size - 1
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ConvViewHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.conversaciones,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ConvViewHolder(view)
}

class ConvViewHolder(vista: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista) {


    val convImg: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.convImg)
    val convStatus: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.convStatus)
    val convName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.convName)
    val convUnread: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.convUnread)
    val convTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.convTime)


}
```

Thanks for any help or hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your **show ()** method, you are creating new Adapter every time with the new dataset. You have to append the new items to the adapter's list and adapter should be set to list once. Helpful tutorial can be found at [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8).

Comment: Thank you! I changed List<> to ArrayList<> and followed the guide and it worked, as you said creating the adapter one time.